# Is there a way to enforce strict url interpretation from a certain folder down?

Tags: url, .htaccess

An area of my site has a folder (let's call it "test") with a series of sub folders having unique names, based on a six digit code. I want any incorrect queries to that folder that are only one character different from an existing url to always return a 404 error, rather than redirecting to the very similar existing url, as it does presently.

EG: if **.../test/abc001/sample.txt** exists, and **.../test/abc002/sample.txt** doesn't, I need the second query to return a 404 rather than a redirect to the first url.

Can this be done in an .htaccess file?

Comment: Think your Apache does this, I forgot the name of the module, but I´m sure there is something that rediricts the user if he just typed one or two chararcters wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An upvote goes to Pekka but I can't really accept his answer as the correct one because, in *my* case at least, it wasn't. As I commented under his solution, the correct answer was provided by my hosting company who instructed me to use this directive:

```
CheckSpelling off
```

That is not to say that Pekka's answer won't be correct for other users facing a similar problem. The Apache [reference for mod_speling](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_speling.html) states that CheckSpelling is off by default, so my hosting company are clearly overriding that default in the first place.

Anyway, thanks to those who tried to help.

Answer (score 2):

This directive

```
Options -MultiViews
```

should turn off the behaviour you describe.

Background [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/content-negotiation.html) (search for the "Multiviews" section) and reference on the `Options` directive [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#options).

Comment: Hmm... I've tried adding an .htaccess file to the **test** folder with just that line in it, but it doesn't seem to make any difference. Requests to the second (non-existent) url are still being redirected to the first. Does this setting take time to take effect?

Comment: @Antagony no, the setting should take effect straight away. Hmm, this could have a number of reasons - it could e.g. have been defined in the central config file that the option can't be turned off in a `.htaccess` file. Are you sure there are no other htaccess rules in some other place along the path?

Comment: @Pekka: The only other .htaccess file is in the root and all it does is specify a custom 404 redirect and the version of PHP to use. I'm looking at the hosting company's FAQ and AFAICT they don't block the option; in fact they actually recommmnd using it exactly as you wrote it above if mod_rewrite is being used.

Comment: @Antagony Really strange. Can you try placing the .htaccess one directory level above the current one? mod_rewrite is not being used anywhere?

Comment: @Pekka: Well the next folder up is the root so I've edited the existing .htaccess file and added the line at the top, but it's still the same I'm afraid. And no, I'm not using mod_rewrite anywhere.

Comment: I've sent an email to the hosting company to see if they can shed any light on this problem. I'm pretty sure it will be something to do with them, as they're notorious for not providing features that are considered standard everywhere else. I'll post back here when I get a response.

Comment: I've had a reply from the hosting company. They told me to use the directive **"CheckSpelling off"**, which I have and it's worked! According to the [Apache reference](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_speling.html), this is usually off by default.